# Is it possible to do a professional internship while a Ph.D. student?

Tags: phd, internship

I have this opportunity in a company as an intern which i am interested in. As a Ph.D. student is it recommended to go for industry ?

Thanks

Comment: Closely related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/160140/i-am-a-phd-candidate-and-i-have-been-offered-an-internship-that-i-want-to-take

Comment: The answer depends upon your adviser and your program. Some programs require internships (because they want students to gain experience). Others prohibit them (because they want students only doing research/teaching). Many programs are somewhere in between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point in your career do one thing and do it well. You’re developing mental discipline and perseverance along with your intelligence and knowledge of a field. If you have the capacity and talent and resilience needed, a summer internship might be useful to you. What does your advisor think about it?

Comment: I havent yet talked about to my advisor, but for a short period internship (3 months) i don't think he'd say no

Answer (score 0):

It is possible based on your evaluation by your advisor. If he agrees to it, all you've to keep in perspective is to be able to coop with a shift of environments after you return back to your Ph.D work. However, if you're working on the same field in your professional internship as your Ph.D (which is obvious, mostly). An internship will surely help you in expanding your network of connections who share the same interest as you which is also a boost for both your research prospects and your career in general. However, you should also understand that Ph.D shouldn't be considered just like any other course. It is a process of gaining expertise, professional experience, understanding the values of ethics, deadlines, guidance, mentorship etc. It is also a process of realizing your own potential and abilities to challenge yourself based on the problem in perspective at various points in time. It's about sticking to the same thing even after failing uncountable times, thereby enhancing your thinking capabilities and in turn giving rise to new possibilities, and amazing research results which therefore provide some/great value to a field.